# Is there a way to output a .eps or vector file using FPDF?

Tags: php, vector, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm trying to layout a business card on a PDF with the [FPDF class](http://www.fpdf.org) using a form field that the user fills out. I have been able to create the text needed for the card, but I have a logo that I want to output as well.

The problem I am facing is that I can only find a way to add an Image as a JPEG and it looks pixelated when the user zooms in on the PDF. **Is there a way to output a vector file on the PDF so when the user zooms, it retains the crisp quality?**

Here are the methods that FPDF allows: http://fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php

Comment: Probably not natively. This person also has a similar quest: http://www.fpdf.org/phorum/read.php?f=1&i=48020&t=48020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm

So GIF, JPEG, PNG are supported. Using pure the FPDF library you should convert the images to a valid type.

However extensions are there ;)
http://staff.dasdeck.de/valentin/fpdf/fpdf_eps/

// Roland